# How do I get all the text from a web page using UI Automation?

Tags: vb.net, ui-automation

Having never used UI Automation before I have been trying for a whole day to try and code it to get all the text from a web page. So far the best I've managed is some code which gets the titlebar text (the hwnd is a chrome browser):

```
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim hwnd As IntPtr = 395018
    Dim window = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hwnd)
    Dim titleBar = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TitleBar))
    sb.Append(vbLf & titleBar.Current.Name.ToString())
    Clipboard.SetText(sb.ToString)
```

This is great, for what it is, but I'd like to go through every element on the whole page, obtaining the element type and the content - then I can filter it and do what I need to do with that data as normal.

Presumably somebody who understands UI Automation will be able to achieve this in about two seconds flat, and I will marvel at how easy it was all along, but right now I'm totally flummoxed, please help!

Thank you in advance

Rich

Comment: You have to first find the active Document, e.g., `dim document = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Document))`, then find all the document's descendants (not children) with one or more conditions, e.g., `AutomationElement.FrameworkIdProperty, "Chrome"` (unfiltered, in practice, get them all, or setup an `OrCondition` with `ControlType.Text` + `ControlType.Hyperlink` etc.), maybe use LINQ to filter those that have null `Name` or no ValuePattern etc., not clear what you want to find

Comment: Hi Jimi

Thanks for replying.

A particular site has a table - the data isn't copyable with Ctrl+C, nor is it in the html. But it IS visible with inspect.exe. So I believe UI Automation is the way to go.

The table isn't dynamic, but does change throughout the day. I would like to copy all data from the table into a string - the whole page, descendents, the lot - I'm right at home manipulating the string. But UI Automation is brand new to me - I don't know what I'm doing so it's guesswork!

Could you provide a function that would obtain that data?

Thanks

Rich

Comment: Your are using the outdated wrapper for UIA version 2. You'll propably have more luck using UIA 3 (requires 3rd party wrapper, e. g. [FlaUI](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI)). Alternatively use a framework specifically made to [automate web browsers](https://www.selenium.dev/).

Comment: Thank you zett42 for your reply - the problem there is that again, I would be attempting to use something brand new to me, I wouldn't have a clue where to start in trying to code it. If you were to post some code that would do the job with selenium then I would go and install selenium, otherwise I would just be guessing again.

Comment: Sorry, I've never attempted something like that. I would have to research this as well. There is plenty of documentation and examples about selenium though. E. g. a quick search revealed this [Python example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-all-text-of-the-page-using-selenium-in-python/) about getting all text from a webpage.